# changing the open icon into close icon when accordion is clicked (active open)

Tags: html, css

so far I have this code accordion. I've included *open and closed icons on "accordion class".

```css
.accordion::after {
content: " ";
background: url("../image/icons/w-open.svg");   <!-- icon when not open-->
right: 0;
display: block;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 28px;
width: 28px;
margin: 10px auto;
}
.accordion[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background: url("../image/icons/w-close.svg");   <!-- icon when open-->
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">                          
  <a class="accordion defaultcolor">
    Accordion Title
  </a>  

  <div class="panel">
    <p>Accordion Text Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The collapsing accordions are working fine, except the changing icons when the accordion is collapsed (open).

how could I successfully working the changing icons smoothly?

FOR UPDATE: I use this js to be able to do the active(show) accordion:

```
var accordions = document.querySelectorAll("a.accordion");

 for (var i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
   accordions[i].onclick = function() {
     this.classList.toggle("active");
       this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
         hideAll(this);
   };
 }

 function hideAll(exceptThis) {
    for (var i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
      if (accordions[i] !== exceptThis) {
        accordions[i].classList.remove("active");
          accordions[i].nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");
     }
   }
 }
```

this js code is perfectly working fine. but still the icon won't change.

Anyone can help me of this problem?

Comment: You apply the icon to the after pseudo-element. When it is expanded you have it on the item itself. This might be an issue.

Comment: From the comment above, please try to use this selector `.accordion[aria-expanded="true"]::after`.

Comment: .accordion[aria-expanded="true"]::after --> I did this already but it doesn't work

Comment: is there a chance to use javacript? is there anyone who can?

Answer (score 0):

For this you could be usind the html  "details" and "summary" tags. These function like an accordion and give an icon as well

```html
 <details>
  <summary>Epcot Center</summary>
  <p>Epcot is a theme park at Walt Disney World Resort featuring exciting attractions, international pavilions, award-winning fireworks and seasonal special events.</p>
</details>
```

Comment: Please give this answer an upvote if it is what you're looking for

Comment: sorry. but I am using my own custom icon.

Comment: oh, then perhaps you could photoshop a revrse image of that icon, and then use js, to switch between them, should i provide code?

Comment: or you could just transform the image using css properties

Comment: can you provide me a code?

Comment: ok,ill try my best, but itll take 10 minutes

Comment: umm, i'm rly sorry but i wasnt able to do that, ig im not rly advanced at js

Comment: it's okay. I think this case is difficult because all of us didn't know how to fix it.